# If $a \equiv b\pmod{m^2}$, then prove $ a \equiv b\pmod{m}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How would I go about proving

$$ a \equiv b\pmod{m}$$
given

$$ 
a \equiv b\pmod{m^2} 
$$

I suspected this was false, so I tried to find a counterexample using a [program](https://gist.github.com/MayorMonty/d15ad34cd5e7558da37c0910a4fecefb), and there does not appear to be a counterexample for $m$ in (2, 16).

What I have tried so far:
$$ 
a \equiv b\pmod{m^2} 
$$
$$
a = b + m^2k
$$
$$
a - b = m^2k
$$
$$
\sqrt{a - b} = \sqrt{m^2k}
$$

Which would imply that $\sqrt{a-b} \equiv 0\pmod{m}$ assuming that $k$ is a perfect square. It feels like I'm barking up the wrong tree, however, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: $m$ divides $m^2$.

Comment: Just use the definitions. So $m^2\mid b-a$ implies $m\mid (b-a)$.

Comment: Use `\pmod{m}` and `\pmod{m^2}`; it provides the spacing, parentheses, and correct typesetting.

Comment: Interesting exercise to consider the reverse direction; if we have $a\equiv b \bmod m$, what possible relationships are there between $a$ and $b$ considered $\bmod m^2$? This can also crystallize understanding of the answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

$a\equiv b\pmod{m^{2}}$ means that:

$$a-b=pm^{2}$$

For some integer $p$. However, letting $q = pm$, we see:

$$a-b=qm$$

Which is the definition of $\boxed{a\equiv b\ \ (\text{mod}\ m).}$

Note that the converse is certainly false; just let $a = 0$ and $b = m$.

Comment: That really clarifies it! Thank you!

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Answer (score 1):

$a-b=km^2=(km)m$.  This same argument can be used to show that if $a\equiv b \pmod{mn}$ then $a\equiv b \pmod m$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.